# ignore what's inside quotes with csv-parse module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I'm trying to write a csv parser to work with some very complex data and I'm having trouble making the [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) module ignore the delimiters inside quotes. I don't have control over how the data comes except maybe for the double quotes themselves, so I can't really put scape characters to solve it. The parser works by first parsing lines with '|', then '@', then ';'.

this is an example of the data I'm trying to process:

```
recognitionDate | training
"2021-08-17"    | "01|0009";"random string";"2"@"01|0009";"random string 2";"2"
```

Currently i'ts breaking on the training column due the '|' at '01|0009' after the '@'.

This is the code for the parser:

```
const getData = (data, delimiter) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rows = []
  
    const rtrim = delimiter === '|' || delimiter === '@'? false : true

    const parser = parseCsv(
      data,
      {
        delimiter,
        relax: true,
        ltrim: true,
        rtrim,
      }
    )
    
    parser.on('readable', () => {
      for(let data = parser.read(); data; data = parser.read()){
        rows.push(data)      
      }
    })
  
    parser.on('end', () => {
      resolve(
        delimiter === '|' ?
        rows : 
        rows.flat(1)
      )
    })
  
    parser.on('error', err => {console.log(err)})
  })
}
```

this is how I'm using it:

```
const buildRisk = async (row, header) => {
  const riskObj = {}
    // iterate through each element of each row
    for(let i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
      if(!row[i]) continue
      let fields = await getData(row[i], '@')
      const mainIndex = header[i].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim() + 's'
        riskObj[mainIndex] = []
        for(let j = 0; j < fields.length; j++){
          const objData = await getData(fields[j], ';')
          if(objData.length > 1){
            riskObj[mainIndex].push({})
            for(let k = 0; k < objData.length; k++){
              riskObj[mainIndex][j]['index' + k] = objData[k].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
            } 
          }
          else{
            riskObj[mainIndex] = objData[0].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
          }
        }
      
    }
    return riskObj
}

const main = async () => {
  // first get all rows
  const rows = await getData(data, '|')
  if(!rows.length) return

  
  // get header
  const header = rows.shift()
  console.log(rows)

  // iterate through rows
  for(const row of rows){
    const risk = await buildRisk(row, header)
    console.log(risk)
  }
}
```

and this is the error from the module:

```
CsvError: Invalid Record Length: expect 2, got 3 on line 2
    at Parser.__onRecord (/home/luders/teste/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:773:9)
    at Parser.__parse (/home/luders/teste/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:662:38)
    at Parser._flush (/home/luders/teste/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:483:22)
    at Parser.prefinish (internal/streams/transform.js:147:10)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at prefinish (internal/streams/writable.js:630:14)
    at finishMaybe (internal/streams/writable.js:638:5)
    at Parser.Writable.end (internal/streams/writable.js:582:5)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/luders/teste/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:1186:16)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21) {
  code: 'CSV_INCONSISTENT_RECORD_LENGTH',
  comment_lines: 0,
  empty_lines: 0,
  invalid_field_length: 0,
  lines: 2,
  records: 1,
  columns: false,
  error: undefined,
  header: false,
  index: 3,
  column: 3,
  quoting: false,
  record: [
    '"2021-08-17"    ',
    '"01|0009";"random string";"2"@"01',
    '0009";"random string 2";"2"'
  ]
}
```

As you can see, It's parsing three columns when it should be parsing 2.

How could I make it ignore whats inside the double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not a valid way of escaping csv. A whole field needs to be enclosed in quotes and the quotes inside it should be also escaped as double quotes. You need to do some pre-processing here. The valid format of csv would be:

```
recognitionDate | training
"2021-08-17"    | " ""01|0009"";""random string"";""2""@""01|0009"";""random string 2"";""2"" "
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but the double double quotes makes it so weird.. Ty, though